# The "RazorGenerate" task was not found. Trying to run a Blazor project in a Rider IDE and always get this error. What's wrong?

Tags: c#, razor, rider, blazor

I'm trying to run a Blazor Solution in my Rider IDE. 
I'm currently using the SDK 3.0.100-preview3-010431 at the time of writing this and I'm also hyper new to razor pages.
After the projects are loaded, the [MySilyProject].Client solution issues a warning:

Project '[MySilyProject].Client' load finished with warnings: The "RazorGenerate" task was not found. Check the following: 1.) The name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class. 2.) The task class is "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.) The task is correctly declared with  in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located in the "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100-preview3-010431" directory. at (93:5)

I cannot proceed because of this and Blazor pages aren't compiled or executed.

This is the reason for the build failure:
  Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.Component.targets(93, 5): [MSB4036] The "RazorGenerate" task was not found. Check the following: 1.) The name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class. 2.) The task class is "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.) The task is correctly declared with  in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located in the "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100-preview3-010431" directory.

I downloaded .vsix file from the VS Marketplace (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidEbbo.RazorGenerator), but the file doesn't recognize the jetbrains IDE.

In the IDE, I tried running the file haphazardly from my IDE, but nothing happened. Tbh, I don't know if I went through this route appropriately

Also went through NuGet: tried Microsoft.AspNet.Razor(3.2.7) and RazorGenerator.Mvc(2.4.9). Warning still persists, and the pages aren't executed

What did I do wrong? Please help?

Comment: I suspect using Rider for a bleeding edge and unreleased technology is not going to go smoothly.  MS provides first class support for Blazor in VS2019 Preview and VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have matching version for MVC and for Blazor files. Make sure that you do not include `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design` package.